# Remove rows have duplicate value in two columns

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file with four columns

```
3022751,6656,7656,T029957
3022751,6054,7054,T029957
3022751,10400,10400,T029958
3022751,10400,10400,T029958
```

I want to remove the rows which have duplicates in column 2 and 3. So my expected output is like this

```
3022751,6656,7656,T029957
3022751,6054,7054,T029957
```

My this awk script is working fine but not deleting the duplicated row like this

```
awk '!x[$2,$3]++' FS=","
```

current output is

```
3022751,6656,7656,T029957
3022751,6054,7054,T029957
3022751,10400,10400,T029958
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think `!x[$2,$3]++` would remove lines where $2 == $3?

Comment: You mean to erase rows in which fields two and three are equal or to eliminate all rows that have same value in column two of another row (and the same for column three)???  In the case you exposed, both rules apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$2!=$3' file
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks for help, Ed.

Answer (score 1):

with `grep`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
3022751,6656,7656,T029957
3022751,6054,7054,T029957
3022751,10400,10400,T029958
3022751,10400,10400,T029958

$ grep -vE '^[^,]+,([^,]+),\1' ip.txt 
3022751,6656,7656,T029957
3022751,6054,7054,T029957
```

- `^[^,]+,` first column and `,`
- `([^,]+)` capture second column
- `\1` back-reference the captured group
- so, if such a match occurs, do not print the line, courtesy `-v` option

Comment: This might remove more lines than intended if the nature of the fourth column were to change.

Comment: @potong, true - my answer is totally specific to given input and required processing... one can possibly adapt the regex accordingly or use `-P` option for lookahead/lookbehind constructs for other cases.. `awk/perl` will be better off in generic cases..

Comment: @potong, on further analysis, found that my earlier regex would remove lines where 3rd and 4th column were same as well.. so modified now to restrict only to 2nd and 3rd column match.. thanks :)